# wxPython: How do you specify the width of a specific column using one of the wx.sizer classes?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm attempting to set up something like this: [image]

However, I'm having a bunch of trouble in figuring it out. I made this general purpose function to wrap a list of objects in a `wx.gridsizer`, and then add that to a `wx.StaticBoxSizer` to get the border around everything. Then it return the `staticBox` sizer to main to be added to the main vertical boxsizer.

```
def buildHorizontalSizer(self, objects, label=None):
    if label:
        box = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, -1, label)
        # for i in dir(box):
        #   print i
        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, wx.HORIZONTAL)
    else:
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    grid = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=3, vgap=0)
    for i in range(len(objects)):
        if i==0:
            grid.Add(objects[i], flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        else:
            grid.Add(objects[i], flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    sizer.Add(grid)
    return sizer
```

In each field, from left to right, there is a StaticText, TextCtrl, and then a Button.

How do I configure the cells so that they have different widths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
objects[i].SetMinSize((width,height))
```

Should do what you want ... you may have to also call

```
objects[i].SetSize((width,height))
```

before adding it to the sizer

Comment: GridSizers are for situations where you want all the controls in a grid that has all the same sized cells. This is good for calculator buttons. A FlexGridSizer is similar to a GridSizer but allows for different sized rows and columns. I think this is what you want to use. I still want to know if there is a method that can set the maxium or minimum width size of a column.